# Adding a prefix to a paragraph field on Gravity Forms

Tags: php, wordpress, gravityforms

I was wondering if its possible to add a function that will add a prefix to a normal paragraph field in Gravity Forms. If so how do I go about doing this?

An Example:
Lets say you have a text field ~ **Reference**

*User enters 7893*

When the user submits the form it should add a **prefix ~ MyCompanyName**

So it comes out as: **Reference: MyCompanyName 7893**

Help would really be appreciated!